# Login to GCP instance as a different user not as a root user

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform

I have a GCP ubuntu 18.04.03 instance and I created a different user in ubuntu like 'David', 'Ayush' and 'Paul' using the command:

```
adduser David
```

Every user has their own password, Now I want Ayush to log in as a 'Ayush' user and David as a 'David' user using putty, I don't want them to log in as a 'root' user so is there any way to achieve that?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you connect to the VM? Is the password usage be a requirement? Or can you use certificates?

Comment: I connect to VM through putty using the public key, but that login me as a root user

Comment: Can you share your putty connection configuration with your parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add ssh public key to /home/ayush/.ssh/authorized_keys, this will define that ssh going to connect to VM as ayush.

Comment: Thanks for replying but I didn't get it properly but just to be confirmed just say I created a pair of a key using `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/mysshkey -C ayush`, now should I add `mysshkey.pub` to `/home/ayush/.ssh/`, but again how can i log in as other than a 'ayush' user.

Comment: you need to add your key to /home/ayush/.ssh/authorized_keys and when you connect to ssh you need to specify that you want to connect as user ayush

Comment: Three things you specify when connect to ssh: host, user and identity file.

Comment: Ok now I can log in as ayush if I use key that i generated, but one last thing that i wanna ask is, do I have to create different keys for different users?

Comment: No, you can add same key for them all. Just if someone lay hands on that key he will also be able to access all those accounts. So think of balance between convinient usage and security.